# e(fx)clipse The import of javafx cant be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, javafx

Hey I just installed e(fx)clipse plugin for eclipse and created a new JavaFX project.

The thing is all the javafx imports can`t be resolved, even though the Library seems to in the build path. Here are some screenshots to show you what I mean:

[image: here you see the errors]
[image: build path]
[image: here is what happens if I try to add the library manually]

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your e(fx)clipse can't find the `jfxrt.jar`. Try reinstalling the pluging or you can manually add the jar to your build path !

Comment: Try removing the JavaFX SDK from your build path and add it manually via "Add Library" again

Comment: In case you run E(fx)clipse under Ubuntu 15.04 (or higher) this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34244308/2849346

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the 'jfxrt.jar' manually

Comment: Well - we'd better find out why the jfxrt.jar is not found let's debug that in our forum

Comment: In case you run E(fx)clipse under Ubuntu 15.04 (or higher) this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34244308/2849346