# e(fx)clipse JavaFX still missing

Tags: javafx, efxclipse

I am running XUbuntu x64 14.04.4 LTS on my PC, with eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and JDK 8 properly linked up to my eclipse (via ini file).

So basically, I "upgradet" to e(fx)clipse. Then I crated a new "JavaFX project". When I tried to run it, I got the error `The import javafx.application cannot be resolved`.

A quick google search brought up, that [I need to add the `jfxwt.jar` from my java 1.8 directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389150/efxclipse-the-import-of-javafx-cant-be-resolved) (in my case `/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/`).

But the error didn't went away. I also tried the build options but nothing seemed to change anything.

Comment: Do you mean "jfxrt.jar"?

Comment: @DVarga omg thanks. Yeah it was pretty late. I added the wrong lib. If you want, you can post that as an answer and I'll mark it. :)

Comment: @DVarga that wasn't the problem after all :s - postet my sollution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I included the wrong jar. whoops. thanks to @DVarga for the tip.

But that wasn't the problem. So here are all the steps I took, to create a working e(fx)clipse environment:

1. Download the latest eclipse version and [add the e(fx)clipse package](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html).
2. Update to the latest [**JDK**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and reference that in the eclipse.ini file (1)
3. [Tell ecplipse the path for the latest JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11596444/4141651). Although this tutorial is for MACs, it works pretty much the same in linux. There are a few differences tho:

   1. The preferences menu is in `window > preferences`
   2. The JRE type is not `MacOS X VM` but rather `Standard VM`
   3. The JRE home path is the `jdk1.8.0_VERSION` folder (in my case `/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_91`)

I didn't need to add any other jar for javaFX to work properly.

## (1) How to add the Java 1.8 path to eclipse

if you get the error `"JavaFX was disabled because your java version is to old"` (or something like this) you need to update to at least Java 1.8 and edit the `eclipse.ini` file in the eclipse folder.

There you have to look for the line `-vm`. In the next line is a path to an old Java version. Change that to the new path. It should look like this: `/path/to/jdk1.8.0_VERSION/jre/bin/` in my case it is `/opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/`